# How to limit frame transfer in Gnu Radio Companion?

Tags: software-defined-radio, gnuradio, hackrf

I have as source a bit frame, then I modulate it, to finally transmit it with my HackRF. I can receive and decode it normally with another HackRF.
However I would like to limit to a number of frame the transmission of this frame. 
Currently, it works like a infinite loop. My expected behaviour would be to transmit it only once or twice but not that much.
My final objective is to change the source (modify the bit frame) after every transmission.

However, I didn't find a way to limit my transmission. 
Then, when I will achieve this first step, I will look into this second step.

Here is my Gnu Radio Graph 
[image]

Comment: it's not clear how your program looks like; do you have a flow graph to share?

Comment: I edited in order to add the flow graph

Comment: I don't know the *AIS Frame Builder* block; where is it from? Does it come with documentation?

Comment: It is just a block to organize my frame with preambule, start/stop flag and everything which is needed. And I would like to send only once this frame.

Comment: well, that block is not doing what you want it to do – so, where is it from? Did you write it yourself? If so, where's the code?

Comment: I use this project https://github.com/trendmicro/ais. I think you want to see this block https://github.com/trendmicro/ais/blob/master/gr-aistx/grc/AISTX_Build_Frame.xml. I though that the repeat value was to repeat or not of transmission, but if I change to false, there is no impact